# Cannot connect component inside React Route to redux store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to connect my component that is placed inside a Route to a redux store, but without any success. Running the program throws an error saying: `TypeError: props.setIsLoggedIn is not a function`
Connecting store to components outside of Route (e.g. MenuBar) works without any problems.

Important part of file containing Routes:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
          <Provider store = {store}>
            <Router>
              <div  className = {classes.pageLayout}>
                <TopBar />
                <MenuBar />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact  path ="/" 
                                component={<Home/>}/>
                    <Route exact  path ="/home" 
                                component={<Home/>}/>
                    <Route exact path ="/login"  
                                component= {<LoginPage/>}/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
          </Router>
        </Provider>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Important part of LoginPage file:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const setIsLoggedIn = isLoggedIn => ({
  type: "SET_IS_LOGGED_IN",
  isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn
});

const LoginForm = (props) => {
  props.setIsLoggedIn(true);
  return (<div>Contains some components.</div>);
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setIsLoggedIn
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage);
```

Comment: Where do you pass `setIsLoggedIn` to the `LoginForm` component?

Comment: is setIsLoggedIn is an action?

Comment: setIsLoggedIn is an action creator, for now I have it in the LoginPage file, it's above LoginForm component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redux `connect` stuff is all fine here - `LoginPage` will have the `setIsLoggedIn` prop - you don't show the code for `LoginPage` but most probably you are just not passing that prop through to `LoginForm`?

i.e.

```
const LoginPage = (props) => (
  ...
  <LoginForm 
    setIsLoggedIn={props.setIsLoggedIn} 
    ...
  />
  ...
)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I got lost in my own source code it seems :/